# In complex variables, what is the behavior of e^z as x,y->positve or negative infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

Consider $e^{x+iy}=e^x(cosy+isiny)$. Consider the following cases and my solutions

Case I-$$\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{x+iy} = \infty$$
Case II-$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} e^{x+iy} = 0$$
Case III-$$\lim_{y\to\infty} e^{x+iy} = undefined$$
Case IV-$$\lim_{y\to-\infty} e^{x+iy} = undefined$$

Since we are working in the complex plane, would this be correct? I am aware that the point of infinity is only allowed for the extended complex plane, so..Also, can a function be undefined if it oscillates as it tends to negative or positive infinity?

Comment: The point at infinity is what we call an "essential singularity".  You may find it instructive to read the material on essential singularities in a complex analysis textbook.  When you understand Picard's Theorem, then you will **really** know your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Your solutions are essentially correct. Only two almost-notational issues:

1) The complex infinite $\infty_{\mathbb{C}}$ is not conceptually the same thing as the usual real infinite $\infty$ as you're allowed to diverge following a path not contained in the real line. Notice that if $y\not\in\pi\mathbb{Z}$ then $i\sin(y)\neq0$ and your path is a line different that the real axis. So in the first case I'd rather say that it is equal to $\infty_{\mathbb{C}}$, or (in a more conservative perspective) that it does not exist.

2) As for the two last limits I would not say that they are undefined as this statement could lead to think that they exist. They do not exist; i.e. they don't coincide with any number (even in the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty_{\mathbb{C}}\}$).